# Java JFuzzyLogic sourceforge running demos

Tags: java, fuzzy-logic, jfuzzylogic

Has anyone successfully run the JFuzzyLogic demos?  I downloaded the zip file, unzipped it.  Was able to run the tip example but there are several others which did not run.  Also the eclipse project seemed not to have net in the source folder which prevented me from running them.  How do you setup JFuzzyLogic to run all the demos. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I was able to run all three demos (Tipper, InvertedPendulum, and parameterOptimization).  I had to modify the fcl file to get the parameterOptimization demo to run and even then it didn't converge on an answer (just a bunch of NaN results).

Getting the demos to run wasn't easy.  I installed the jFuzzyLogic software in my Eclipse Helios version, but the fcl editor didn't work.  Basically, Eclipse just ignored the whole thing, so I unzipped jFuzzyLogic.jar and imported the project.  I had to create a 'src' folder and move the 'net' directory under it.  After that it all worked.

Answer (score 1):

It is not that complicated...
To run the demo all you have to do is double click on the JAR file.

If double click doesn't work, just run "java -jar jFuzzyLogic.jar", as the website says.